# not getting push notification to android device from server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using example of GCM from [Android Hive GCM example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/), i have shared server so i have put my server code on that

My device is successfully registered

[image]

also in server and in database i am getting entry

in mysql the entry is

[image]

In server

[image]

i am getting success logcat is also

```
     11-29 17:55:17.796: V/GCMBaseIntentService(29081): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-572954477211-1
     11-29 17:55:17.796: E/GCMRegistrar(29081): internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
     11-29 17:55:17.796: V/GCMRegistrar(29081): Registering receiver
     11-29 17:55:17.796: D/GCMBaseIntentService(29081): handleRegistration: registrationId = APA91bG5js7Op0v4VQe9Rj_MlXVggCwGZI0KQutCjbBLtu5t07BHguKvWhQiU6JauTOvF9Ilzn9-_cbXuTg0HxUg9dL7FNIZvlt1zB6LIFHlBZ8mi-ebRyo9KZTO1XpcLzLBKQLSHyCTsBUSeuO2tlJY9Tm3o9zphA, error = null, unregistered = null
     11-29 17:55:17.796: D/GCMRegistrar(29081): resetting backoff for com.igeniusdev.gcmexample
     11-29 17:55:17.846: V/GCMRegistrar(29081): Saving regId on app version 1
     11-29 17:55:17.886: I/GCMIntentService(29081): Device registered: regId = APA91bG5js7Op0v4VQe9Rj_MlXVggCwGZI0KQutCjbBLtu5t07BHguKvWhQiU6JauTOvF9Ilzn9-_cbXuTg0HxUg9dL7FNIZvlt1zB6LIFHlBZ8mi-ebRyo9KZTO1XpcLzLBKQLSHyCTsBUSeuO2tlJY9Tm3o9zphA
     11-29 17:55:17.916: D/NAME(29081): amit
     11-29 17:55:17.916: I/AndroidHive GCM(29081): registering device (regId = APA91bG5js7Op0v4VQe9Rj_MlXVggCwGZI0KQutCjbBLtu5t07BHguKvWhQiU6JauTOvF9Ilzn9-_cbXuTg0HxUg9dL7FNIZvlt1zB6LIFHlBZ8mi-ebRyo9KZTO1XpcLzLBKQLSHyCTsBUSeuO2tlJY9Tm3o9zphA)
     11-29 17:55:17.916: D/AndroidHive GCM(29081): Attempt #1 to register
     11-29 17:55:17.956: V/AndroidHive GCM(29081): Posting 'email=kinjal.amr@gmail.com&regId=APA91bG5js7Op0v4VQe9Rj_MlXVggCwGZI0KQutCjbBLtu5t07BHguKvWhQiU6JauTOvF9Ilzn9-_cbXuTg0HxUg9dL7FNIZvlt1zB6LIFHlBZ8mi-ebRyo9KZTO1XpcLzLBKQLSHyCTsBUSeuO2tlJY9Tm3o9zphA&name=amit' to http://ithinkapp.com/gcmTest/register.php
    11-29 17:55:17.956: E/URL(29081): > http://ithinkapp.com/gcmTest/register.php
    11-29 17:55:19.696: V/GCMRegistrar(29081): Setting registeredOnServer status as true until 2013-12-06 17:55:19.703
    11-29 17:55:19.736: V/GCMBaseIntentService(29081): Releasing wakelock
```

everything is fine but when i try to send a message from server and press send button message will be send but not getting push notification in device

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no not getting any error in server side or not getting any error in device also

Comment: Please post your manifest file and code.

Comment: i have entirely copy and paste code from this site http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ just change package name

Answer (score 0):

please change your api key as **Key for server apps (with IP locking)** and change key to your config.php file.

http://gcm-alert.appspot.com/ also check this site for checking your server side code is working properly or not.

Comment: Sending name to the server:
Guest

Server replies:
Failure: HTTP Status Code: 401

Comment: 1) run your code.
2) put log of your regID in logcat you regID and copy it.
3) go to this site any pass API KEY from your console. and RegID you got from yout logcat output.
4) no need to pass any parameter right now from testing.
5) click send